# NestJS HttpService Call Multiple Endpoints Simultaneously

Tags: node.js, axios, rxjs, observable, nestjs

I am using NestJS `HttpModule` to make GET request for one end point. The code is somewhat like this:

```
@Injectable
export class AnimalService {
  constructor(private httpService: HttpService){}
  
  getAnimalData(variant: string): Observable<AxiosResponse<Animal>> {
    return this.httpService
      .get(`http://animal.test/${variant}`)
      .pipe(map((response) => response.data));
  }
}
```

And now I want to create a method which calls multiple endpoints simultaneously.

```
getAllAnimalsData() {
  // const variants = ['birds', 'cats', 'dogs'];
  // call 
  //   http://animal.test/birds
  //   http://animal.test/cats
  //   http://animal.test/dogs
  // simultaneously
  // and process the response data
}
```

How can I achieve this using NestJS `HttpModule`?
How can I process every result?
How can I handle if there is a partial error (e.g. 1 of 3 request has an error)?

Comment: Hitting several endpoints does not seem a good idea, Why don't you just create an endpoint which returns the array itself?

Comment: The problem is those endpoints are from third party. I cant change them directly or suggest them to add more endpoint

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make multiple http requests simultaneously you can use the RxJS `forkJoin` operator. I also added a `catchError` to each Observable so that any errors will be passed to the subscribe callback. The subscribe callback triggers when all Observables are finished.

```
getAllAnimalsData() {
  const variants = ['birds', 'cats', 'dogs'];
  
  forkJoin(
    variants.map(v => 
      getAnimalData(v).pipe(catchError(e => of(e)))
    )
  )
  .subscribe(([r1, r2, r3]) => /* ... */)
}
```